# accurev command revert to basis

Tags: command-line-interface, accurev

I am trying to get a CLI command for "revert to basis" of all the overlapping dll's in my workspace.

1. Which command should I use for this - `purge` or `revert` ?
2. I want to do this action only for overlapped dll files in my workspace. What is the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Purge
2. Get a list of all the overlap files.  Run the command "accurev stat -o -ffl > list.txt"

Then run the command "accurev purge -l list.txt"